# When calling a Pie is it possible to do multiple LMB licks before it goes away?

Tags: python, interface, pie-menu

for example when you include a menu with multiple options in a pie and you want to click two. After each LMB click the pie goes away, so you have to call the pie menu twice.

Comment: I think at present there's nothing special about pie menus, in the sense that they act the same as regular spawned menus like (the W menu). you can only click on one item and then the menu has served its purpose. Though I fully agree that a way to pin the menu according to some rule-set would allow for interesting usability features.

Comment: Thanks - Many of my pies have all buttons and "2" is mapped to a box with options. So there it would be nice to spawn the pie and the set your options. This might be worth to ask the devs to consider.